# Synchronously Execute Simple Unix Terminal Commands using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix

I want to execute synchronously Simple Unix Terminal Commands using Node.js.and return to client. My code is:

```
var exec=require('child_process').exec;
    var cmd='dir';
    exec(cmd,function(error,stdout,stderr){
      console.log(stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
      if(error!=null){
            console.log(error);
      } 
      return stdout;
      console.log(stdout);        
   });
```

Comment: Describe what is wrong with your code, the expected output, in short, what is your problem.

Comment: Also, `dir` isn't generally a known command. It may be a shell alias, but those won't be executed using `child_process.exec()`.

Comment: Hi, It executes synchronously,,I want to execute it asynchronously.